# Winston can't run project in WebStorm, but from command line and PM2 it works

Tags: node.js, webstorm, winston

I inherited a legacy project with Winston 2, and have a very strange behaviour. When I start the project with PM2 or by using `node index.js` it works flawlessly. But when I define it as **NODE.js** configuration in WebStorm it exists with the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'logs/info-log.log'
Emitted 'error' event on  instance at:
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/legacy-project/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js:491:16)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at internal/fs/streams.js:321:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:155:23) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'logs/info-log.log'
}
```

There is config for file transport:

```json
{
  "category": "default",
  "name": "info-log",
  "filename": "logs/info-log.log",
  "level": "info"
}
```

Screenshot of WebStorm config:
[image]

Installed version is Winston 2.2.0, and I restricted to it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue was related to the working directory. There're a few apps which nested under the same working directory, which considered to be a root of the project. My mistake was that I defined the working directory as nested path of the sub-project. When I changed it, and instead of this defined full path to `app.js`, it began to work.

[image]